# HTML Editor that can collapse blocks of code by Tag and move them?

Tags: php, html, editor, folding

I am looking for an editor or IDE, preferably one with at least some syntax highlighting capability,   that would let me collapse HTML code blocks by Tag and drag them.  I have Eclipse but it's "folding" option only works on top level Tags like TABLE, etc., not child Tags like TD, TR, etc.  Is there an editor for Windows PCs that has this capability?  I would want to be able to move the block as an Entity around the PHP script page.  For example, frequently I want to move a TD element that contains a large block of code from one row to the other.  Without the ability to collapse the TD element it is an awkward experience visually trying to execute the move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows I generally use Notepad++, TextWrangler does it for me on the Mac and I believe gedit has similar abilities in Linux, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) for a long time now. It differs from Eclipse in many aspects (not all of them good but some great usability tweaks) and it has what you need - it can fold any tag, no matter how deep in hierarchy.

Comment: It also formats the code, not only PHP, but also CSS, JS and HTML. Great editor, I use it myself for PHP based projects all the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dreamweaver for collapse/expand table or any tag